# How to get the path of the image stored in the resources folder of a project in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have some images stores in the resources folder of a project as shown. I am able to find the images through My.Resorces.arc1/arc2/arc3 but i am not able to locate the image called directions2 stored at the same resources folder.

Can anyone please help me on this

[image]

Comment: Try going to Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Resources.resx and then make sure directions2 shows there as a proper image and is called directions2.

Comment: Thank you. It is showing now. Actually the image was not there in the Resources.resx and i pasted there and it is listing now. Thank you

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :D Glad to know you got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Check your image file have proper file extensions [.jpg,.png etc]

2.Rebuild your project and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The path is shown in Resource file. See the [image]